# Error deleting service using ambari

Tags: hadoop, ambari

I'm trying to delete a service that failed to install correctly so that I can attempt to reinstall it.

I couldn't find any options for deleting in the ambari UI so I'm trying to delete using the API.  However, I hit an error message:

```
curl -u admin:admin -H 'X-Requested-By:ambari' -X DELETE \
     'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/BI4_QSE/services/SPARK'
{
  "status" : 500,
  "message" : "org.apache.ambari.server.controller.spi.SystemException: 
               An internal system exception occurred: Cannot remove SPARK.             
               Desired state STARTED is not removable.  
               Service must be stopped or disabled."
}
```

I'm using the dockerised version of IBM Open Platform v4, i.e. IOP_v4000_20150.zip

The ambari version is:

```
[root@rvm /]# ambari-server --version
1.7.0_IBM
```

Below is the output from the GET command:

```
curl -u admin:admin -H 'X-Requested-By:ambari' -X GET \
     'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/BI4_QSE/services/SPARK'
{
  "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/BI4_QSE/services/SPARK",
  "ServiceInfo" : {
    "cluster_name" : "BI4_QSE",
    "maintenance_state" : "OFF",
    "service_name" : "SPARK",
    "state" : "INSTALLED"
  },
  "components" : [
    {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/BI4_QSE/services/SPARK/components/SPARK_CLIENT",
      "ServiceComponentInfo" : {
        "cluster_name" : "BI4_QSE",
        "component_name" : "SPARK_CLIENT",
        "service_name" : "SPARK"
      }
    },
    {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/BI4_QSE/services/SPARK/components/SPARK_JOBHISTORYSERVER",
      "ServiceComponentInfo" : {
        "cluster_name" : "BI4_QSE",
        "component_name" : "SPARK_JOBHISTORYSERVER",
        "service_name" : "SPARK"
      }
    },
    {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/BI4_QSE/services/SPARK/components/SPARK_THRIFTSERVER",
      "ServiceComponentInfo" : {
        "cluster_name" : "BI4_QSE",
        "component_name" : "SPARK_THRIFTSERVER",
        "service_name" : "SPARK"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Question**: how can I delete and reinstall spark?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to run the following sequence of commands to stop and then remove SPARK.

The following command will set state to INSTALLED, aka ensure its not RUNNING.

```
curl -i -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -u admin:admin -X PUT \
     -d '{"RequestInfo":{"context":"Stop Service"},"Body":{"ServiceInfo":{"state":"INSTALLED"}}}' \
     http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/BI4_QSE/services/SPARK
```

The next few commands will ensure each component is stopped.

```
 curl -i -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -u admin:admin -X PUT \
      -d '{"RequestInfo":{"context":"Stop All Components"},"Body":{"ServiceComponentInfo":{"state":"INSTALLED"}}}' \
      http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/BI4_QSE/services/SPARK/components/SPARK_THRIFTSERVER

 curl -i -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -u admin:admin -X PUT \
      -d '{"RequestInfo":{"context":"Stop All Components"},"Body":{"ServiceComponentInfo":{"state":"INSTALLED"}}}' \
      http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/BI4_QSE/services/SPARK/components/SPARK_JOBHISTORYSERVER
```

Finally you can remove the service by executing the following command:

```
 curl -i -H "X-Requested-By: ambari" -u admin:admin -X DELETE \ 
      http://localhost:8080/api/v1/clusters/BI4_QSE/services/SPARK
```

You can then reinstall SPARK using the 'Add Service' wizard in Ambari UI.

Comment: I was facing similar issue but the above command did not help. I've documented the solution here : https://hadooptips.wordpress.com/2015/10/10/full-authentication-is-required-to-access-this-resource-while-deleting-a-servicecomponent-from-ambari/